# What is the significance of the name of the indexer in indexable types?

Tags: typescript

What is the purpose of the name of the indexer in indexable types?

I have an indexable type `Indexable` as below:

```
class Test {
    someProp: string
}

interface Indexable {
    [someString: string]: Test,
    [someNumber: number]: Test
}
```

What is the purpose of the index name `someString` and `someNumber`? I also see indexers defined like `[key: string]` and `[index: string]`. Do the names `key` and `index` have any special meaning?

I cannot find anything related to the name in the official [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).

Comment: It is displayed in intellsense to callers and therefore can provide meaning. I often call it `key`. It is required due to postfix type syntax, a minor annoyance. That said, postfix type syntax is great for many reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a binding identifier to allow a type definition. The grammar definition is:

```
IndexSignature:
   [ BindingIdentifier : string ] TypeAnnotation
   [ BindingIdentifier : number ] TypeAnnotation
```

We usually use `index` or `key` as a default identifier name but we can use any other names.

> See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#394-index-signatures